# How to make animations from single image in processing?

Tags: image, processing

So I  got an image of a player animation( in file 900x900).
I want to load it once and split into `PImage`s 100x100 so that each one of them is a separate `PImage`. I am not a fan of using 81 separate files each 100x100 and loading them all. Is there a way of doing that in Processing.

I could just store `PImage` as one and create 81 `Rectangle` as place of a frame in big image, but how to draw just a part of `PImage`?

Comment: In addition to to Kevin's answer, also check out [`PImage's copy()`](https://processing.org/reference/PImage_copy_.html) and [this long answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55556823/how-do-you-work-with-sprites-and-why-were-they-used-so-widely-in-older-games/55559855#55559855) if you have the time ;)

Answer (score 2):

Questions like this are best answered by looking at the Processing [reference](https://processing.org/reference/).

Specifically, check out the reference for the `PImage` class [here](https://processing.org/reference/PImage.html).

The `get()` function (reference [here](https://processing.org/reference/PImage_get_.html)) allows you to split a `PImage` up into smaller `PImage` instances.

Comment: Oh. I didn't think that was what `get()` does. I thought it just gave a pixel color of given spot in the image. I don't know why. But if that's what it does than thank you. I thought it has to be somewhere there.

Comment: @SkillGG The `get()` function can also give you the color of a specific pixel. It depends on what parameters you pass into it.

Comment: Yeah. I just read too little to notice that. My mistake. I gave up too early.